# Как запустить sh скрипт, который вложен в папку Assets, из андроид приложения

Tags: java, android, shell

Помогите мне найти код для запуска sh скрипта из андроид приложения. Нужен ява код для выполнения при нажатии на кнопку:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
// Обработка нажатия кнопки
public void delete(View view) {
    // Нужно, чтобы запускался здесь

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Код для выполнения бинарника или скрипта:

```
String appFileDirectory = getFilesDir().getPath();
String executableFilePath = appFileDirectory + "/" + FILENAME;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executableFilePath);
```

Для чтения или записи в процесс воспользуемся следующим кодом:

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
```

Алгоритм действия такой:

- добавьте бинарник или скрипт в папку `assets`
- Используйте `getAssets().Open(FILENAME)`, чтобы получить
  `InputStream`.
- Запишите его в `/data/data/APPNAME/files` (например,
  `/data/data/ru.example.runfromassets/files`), где ваше приложение имеет доступ к файлам на запись и исполнение.
- Выполните `/system/bin/chmod 744 /data/data/APPNAME/files/FILENAME`, используя приведенный выше код.
- Выполните исполняемый файл или скрипт, используя приведенный выше код.